# URL detection adobe air desktop widget

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, air, rich-internet-application

I'm new in Adobe Air, I need (urgente!!!) to do a widget with Adobe Air that monitors the  URLs where I navigate and when I enter to  a specific site the widget appears in the front of my screen and display a message. 
The problem is that I don't know how to listen the current URL of my browser using Adobe air (flash).

I was trying with HttpStatusEvent but I can figure aut how to retireve the URL from my browser.

Thanx!!

```
   Carolina
```

Comment: I'm adding a bounty to this because the question I want answered is similar: How to pull the URL of the **active tab/window of the active browser** for use in an Adobe AIR app?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174987/adobe-air-to-detect-url-of-active-browser-tab/4175106#4175106)

This wouldn't be easy; it may be impossible.  There are issues with timers and running AIR/Flash Player minimized.  Things slow down so it is less of a drag on computer performance.  AIR in the background may not respond the same way as an Active AIR application would.

In theory, you can write a Proxy in AIR using sockets and set the local browser to route all requests through the proxy.  That probably isn't practical for wide use.

If you have control over the web page that you want to use to trigger your AIR app, you might be able to put a SWF on your web page and then use a LocalConnection to communicate between the browser SWF and the AIR app, forcing the AIR app to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

AIR has no means to know if browser is running and what it does (barring NativeProcess helpers).

Flextras' answer made me think about proxies... Of course, proxy inside widget isn't practical. If widget is proxy, you can't have internet without it - that's silly. Instead, one can take an open source proxy, inside it check user agent header (to filter browser requests) and probably url (to exclude images, css and js requests). When you have request from browser and for html, you can make proxy open local socket connection to the same port your widget listens and notify it. But this can hardly be done urgently.