# Adobe AIR to detect URL of active browser/tab

Tags: apache-flex, air, webbrowser-control, rich-internet-application

Using Adobe AIR + related technologies, is it possible to detect the URL of the active tab/window of the active browser?

For instance, if my user is surfing in IE8 on `www.example.com/subdirectory/`, can I retrieve that data for use in my Adobe AIR RIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

In theory you could use NativeProcess and run some local machine code to figure it out; assuming the browser exposes it via some API.  OF course, I'm not sure how you'd trigger that code from AIR if the browser was the active window.

Comment: Thank you @Flextras!  Just FYI, I offered a bounty on another user's question that's (almost) identical to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963169/url-detection-adobe-air-desktop-widget